# How to show data of a database in a tableview?

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, tableview, javafx-8

In the database I have 5 records created which are in a tableview. I can select 5 rows but the data is not shown in the tableView. I've tried everything, can anyone help?

The code of my problem:

**initialize**

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    colNome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClientRow, String>(
            "clienteNome"));
    colRG.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClientRow, String>(
            "clienteRG"));
    colPlaca.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClientRow, String>(
            "clientePlaca"));
    colModelo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClientRow, String>(
                        "clienteModelo"));
    colData.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClientRow, String>(
                "clienteData"));

    applyList(daoClient.getListDao());
}
```

**applyList**

```
private void applyList(List<Client> client) {

    ObservableList<ClientRow> listObservable =                FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (Client p : client) {
        String nome = p.getNome();
        String modelo = p.getModelo();
        String placa = p.getPlaca();
        String data = p.getDataInicio().toString();
        String rg = p.getRg();

        listObservable.add(new ClientRow(nome, modelo, placa, data, rg));
    }
    tableClient.setItems(listObservable);


}
```

**class ClientRow**

```
public class ClientRow {

    public final SimpleStringProperty clientNome;
    public final SimpleStringProperty clientRG;
    public final SimpleStringProperty clientPlaca;
    public final SimpleStringProperty clientModelo;
    public final SimpleStringProperty clientData;

    public ClientRow(String clientNome, String clientRG,
            String clientPlaca, String clientModelo, String clientData) {
        this.clientNome = new SimpleStringProperty(clientNome);
        this.clientRG = new SimpleStringProperty(clientRG);
        this.clientPlaca = new SimpleStringProperty(clientPlaca);
        this.clientModelo = new SimpleStringProperty(clientModelo);
        this.clientData = new SimpleStringProperty(clientData);
    }

    public String getclientNome() {
        return clientNome.get();
    }

    public String getclientRG() {
        return clientRG.get();
    }

    public String getclientPlaca() {
        return clientRG.get();
    }

    public String getclientModelo() {
        return clientModelo.get();
    }

    public String getclientData() {
        return clientData.get();
    }

}
```

Comment: Fix your method names in `ClientRow`: `getClientNome()`, `getClientRG()`, etc.

Comment: In `ClientRow`. The method names are wrong; just change them as above.

Comment: Damn, only that! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, how to use for date or calendar?

Comment: and search with values ​​of textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong method names as James_D suggested in the comment. Maybe a bit more in detail:

```
colNome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClientRow, String>("clienteNome"));
```

is linked to `getClienteNome()` in your ClientRow class (which does not exist). So you will have to rename `getclientNome()` to `getClienteNome()`

Same for the other methods. If this helped, don't forget to upvote James_D's comment.

Comment: Damn, only that! Thank you so much!